# How to distinguish user input file path and string

Tags: bash

I am looking for - How to adapt - Auto distiguish between user input file_location and string (can be one string or list of strings one per line) ?

```
#!/bin/bash

fun1(){
arrDomains=()

while read domain
do
     arrDomains+=($domain)
done
for i in ${arrDomains[@]}
do
        echo $i
done > $file_path
return
}

fun2(){
echo "File path is $file_path"
}

read -p "specify the file path or paste domain list" file_path
###### If I specify the file path it should call function - fun2
###### If I copy paste domain list it should call funtions fun1 & fun2
```

Example-
1st scenario: when i type file location

```
specify the file path or paste domain list
   /tmp/filelist
```

2nd scenario: when i copy paste names

```
specify the file path or paste domain list
   name1.w.corp
   name2
   name3.bz.co
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: Yeah so your second scenario simply won't work.  Read will take `name1` and discard the rest

Comment: For that , it should auto distinguish file path & string and execute function as condition. 1st scenario -> requires only fun2  and 2nd scenario --> requires fun1 & fun2

Comment: It's probably possible but definitely not worth the effort.  Just use getopts and/or a proper way to take the arguments.  Also quote all your variables

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to paste the domain list that way but you can check if the input is a file:

```
read -p "specify the file path or paste domain list" file_path
if [[ -f "$file_path" ]]; then
  fun2
else
  fun1
  fun2
fi
```

Comment: But if copy paste list , how it will distinguish between file path & strings ?

Comment: If you copy and paste it will check if the first line is a file, if not it runs fun1 & fun2.  It will produce an error with the second line because it's not a valid command, and it will discard the remaining lines.  Function 1 is going to ask for the list of domains again anyway so it seems like that is more or less what you want.  But please note that you **shouldn't** want that.  It's sloppy

Comment: Function 1 not required to ask -enter domain